# Get SQL of failed statement inside exit handler of MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I am building a stored procedure that executes 10-12 SQL statements.  I'm getting an error 1172, `Result consisted of more than one row`.  I'm trying to figure out which statement is responsible.

The most obvious way is to return the SQL of the statement that raised the error.

Here is my exit handler:

```
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
  BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS @n = NUMBER, @c = ROW_COUNT;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION @n
      @s = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
      @m = MESSAGE_TEXT,
      @e = MYSQL_ERRNO;
    ROLLBACK;
    SELECT @s as RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @e as MYSQL_ERRNO, @m as MESSAGE_TEXT, @n as NUMBER, @c as ROW_COUNT;
  END;
```

What can I add so that it will tell me which of my SQL statements generated the error?

For reference, here is the full stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `unlink_item`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `unlink_item` ( 
  IN item_id         varchar(36), 
  IN parent_id       varchar(36),
  IN author          varchar(64),
  IN conversation_id varchar(36),
  IN transaction_id  varchar(36)
)
BEGIN

  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
  BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS @n = NUMBER, @c = ROW_COUNT;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION @n
      @s = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
      @m = MESSAGE_TEXT,
      @e = MYSQL_ERRNO;
    ROLLBACK;
    SELECT @s as RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @e as MYSQL_ERRNO, @m as MESSAGE_TEXT, @n as NUMBER, @c as ROW_COUNT;
  END;

  START TRANSACTION;

  SET @when = now();

  -- identify the record we are supposed to delete --
  SET @deleted = '123';
  SELECT  `id` 
    FROM  `item_contains`
    WHERE `parent_id` = parent_id
    AND   `child_id`  = item_id
    INTO @deleted;

  -- delete the record --
  DELETE FROM `item_contains`
  WHERE `id` = @deleted;

  -- update the change history for the item_contains table --
  INSERT INTO `change_history` (
    `date_time`,
    `author`,
    `action`,
    `table_name`,
    `record_id`,
    `conversation_id`,
    `transaction_id`
  ) VALUES (
    @when,
    author,
    'delete',
    'item_contains',
    @deleted,
    conversation_id,
    transaction_id
  );

  -- update the change history for the parent item --
  INSERT INTO `change_history` (
    `date_time`,
    `author`,
    `action`,
    `table_name`,
    `record_id`,
    `conversation_id`,
    `transaction_id`
  ) VALUES (
    @when,
    author,
    concat('unlink from ',parent_id),
    'item',
    item_id,
    conversation_id,
    transaction_id
  );

  -- update the change history for the item being unlinked --
  INSERT INTO `change_history` (
    `date_time`,
    `author`,
    `action`,
    `table_name`,
    `record_id`,
    `conversation_id`,
    `transaction_id`
  ) VALUES (
    @when,
    author,
    concat('unlink ',item_id, ' from this'),
    'item',
    parent_id,
    conversation_id,
    transaction_id
  );

  -- if the unlinked item is now orphaned either delete it if it is empty, or re-attach it somewhere to make it accessible --
  SET @instances = 0;

  SELECT count(`id`) 
    FROM `item_contains`
    WHERE `child_id` = item_id
    INTO @instances;

  IF ( @instances = 0 ) THEN

    SET @children = 0;
    SELECT count(`id`) 
      FROM `item_contains`
      WHERE `parent_id` = item_id
      INTO @children;

    IF ( @children = 0 ) THEN

      -- delete the now inaccessible item from the database --
      DELETE FROM `item`
      WHERE `id` = item_id;

      -- update the change history for that item --
      INSERT INTO `change_history` (
        `date_time`,
        `author`,
        `action`,
        `table_name`,
        `record_id`,
        `conversation_id`,
        `transaction_id`
      ) VALUES (
        @when,
        author,
        'delete',
        'item',
        item_id,
        conversation_id,
        transaction_id
      );

    ELSE

      -- get the ID of the orphan folder --
      SET @orphan_id = '123';
      SELECT `id` 
        FROM `item`
        WHERE `name` = '### orphans ###'
        INTO @orphan_id;

      -- move the item into the orphan folder --
      SET @inserted = uuid();
      INSERT INTO `item_contains` (
        `id`,
        `parent_id`,
        `child_id`
      ) VALUES (
        @inserted,
        @orphan_id,
        item_id
      );

      -- update the change history to reflect the orphaning of the item --
      INSERT INTO `change_history` (
        `date_time`,
        `author`,
        `action`,
        `table_name`,
        `record_id`,
        `conversation_id`,
        `transaction_id`
      ) VALUES (
        @when,
        author,
        'orphaned',
        'item',
        item_id,
        conversation_id,
        transaction_id
      );

    END IF;

  END IF;

  SELECT 
    0 AS `RETURNED_SQLSTATE`,
    0 AS `MYSQL_ERRNO`, 
    'Item unlinked' AS `MESSAGE_TEXT`,
    1 as `ROW_COUNT`;

  COMMIT;

END;
```

UPDATE: The root problem was in the first SELECT statement:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `item_contains` 
WHERE  `parent_id` = parent_id 
AND    `child_id` = item_id
```

I had assumed that the left `parent_id` would be the one from `item_contains` and the right `parent_id` would be the stored procedure parameter.  I was mistaken.  Both are interpreted as the stored procedure parameter.  The solution was to alias the table and refer to the fields via the alias, like so:

```
SELECT ic.id FROM item_contains AS ic
WHERE  ic.parent_id = parent_id
AND    ic.child_id = item_id
```

**HOWEVER: the original question still stands:**

Is there something that I can add to my `EXIT HANDLER` that will tell me WHERE in my stored procedure that the error was raised?

Comment: But what is the SQL that causes the sql exception?

Comment: Debugging in stored procedure isn't easy there isn't  anny good debugging function(s) available.

Comment: Can't you share the complete MySQL code?

Comment: @IvanCachicatari that is my question.

Answer (score 1):

All `SELECT ... INTO` statements must return only one row.

For example, The below code may return more than 1 record:

```
SELECT  `id` 
  FROM  `item_contains`
  WHERE `parent_id` = parent_id
  AND   `child_id`  = item_id
  INTO @deleted;
```

You can debug statement storing the result in another variable and `select`:

```
SELECT  count(*) 
  FROM  `item_contains`
  WHERE `parent_id` = parent_id
  AND   `child_id`  = item_id
  INTO @supposed_to_delete;

SELECT @supposed_to_delete;  /*you will see the value after execute*/
```

Another way to make sure only one record (not recommended) is adding a `limit`

```
SELECT  `id` 
  FROM  `item_contains`
  WHERE `parent_id` = parent_id
  AND   `child_id`  = item_id
  LIMIT 1   /* <-- force to return only one record */
  INTO @deleted;
```

Comment: When I execute the SELECT statement on its own, it works.  It only fails in the context of the stored procedure.  There is only one record that matches, which is enforced by constraints on the `item_contains` table, so it can't possibly be returning multiple values.

Comment: Amazingly enough, though, adding `LIMIT  1` seems to work.  Apparently it throws that error even if there is only one matching row.

Comment: Okay, turns out that `WHERE 'parent_id' = parent_id` was not being interpreted the way I thought it was.  The one on the left and the one on the right were both interpreted as the stored procedure parameter.

Comment: But the original question still stands:  Is there a function that I can `SELECT` in my handler that will return the SQL of the failed statement?